# C++ - Convert a string binary chain to a int binary chain

Tags: c++, converters

I try to convert a string like that 00000101 to a int like that 00000101.

But each method I tried, has transformed that chain to something like that: 101 without the 0s.

So how I can do in order to keep the 0s?

Comment: integer 101 is identical to 00000101 as the lead zeros have no significance, if you want the lead zeros *for display* use a string and prepend 8-scale '0's

Comment: Can you articulate how an integer 00000101 is different from an integer 101, either mathematically or in the computer's in-memory representation? Think about this and you'll answer your own question.

Comment: One easy way to get leading zeros: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2ff515a3b5a0438

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? There are solutions to your actual problem I'm sure... A code snippet (with wrong output, I presume) would be helpful

Comment: Actually i have a pixel and i find the binary code of a pixel. For example 00000101. Then i would like to extract each component of this code that is to say : component 1 = 0 , component 2 = 0 etc That's why it's important to me to have the entire chain in int because i have the chain at the beginning in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `01` is `001` is `00001` is all `1`. There is no way to "store" leading zeros for an integer or any other numeric type. It is impossible.

Your best bet is to either store the individual digits in an array of integers, or store the value not as decimal `101`, but as *binary* `101`, or decimal 5. If you treat the integer like an 8 bit byte, you have your `00000101`.

Comment: Okey i need to find another solution. Actually i have a pixel and i find the binary code of a pixel. For example 00000101. Then i would like to extract each component of this code that is to say : component 1 = 0 , component 2 = 0 etc
That's why it's important to me to have the entire chain in int because i have the chain at the beginning in string format.

Comment: Then you're interested in the second part of my answer. You need to store the *binary* value `00000101` and manipulate the individual bits with bitwise operators. You should google `bit manipulation` or `bitwise operators` and start reading; it's not complex and it is very well covered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for int type 00000101 is the same as 101. Zeros before don't really matter in this data type. You can only change the way you display it.